# How to compose different components dynamically with React?

Tags: reactjs

I have two icon components

## Icon1

```
# src/components/Icon/CatIcon/CatIcon.tsx

import React from "react";
...

export const CatIcon: React.FC<Size> = (props) => {
  return (
    ...
  );
};
```

## Icon2

```
# src/components/Icon/DogIcon/DogIcon.tsx

import React from "react";
...

export const DogIcon: React.FC<Size> = (props) => {
  return (
    ...
  );
};
```

## Name

A name component

```
# src/components/Name/PetName/PetName.tsx

type PetNameType = {
  text: string;
};

export const PetName: React.FC<PetNameType> = ({ text }) => {
  return <H2>{text}</H2>;
};
```

## Make Icon and Name together

I want to compile them together with different icons.

```
# src/components/Pet/Pet.tsx

import React from "react";
import { CatIcon, PetName } from "~/components";

export type PetFieldProps = {
  text: string;
};

export const PetField: React.FC<PetFieldProps> = ({
  text,
}) => {
  return (
    <>
      <CatIcon />
      <PetName />
    </>
  );
};
```

This way can fix the `Cat` icon only, or import `DogIcon` to use for another. But is it possible to set animal icon components dynamically in one compose component but not two?

Comment: What is your intended outcome? I'm not sure I follow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you want to set pet icons dynamically then add some more props into the Pet component**

```
# src/components/Pet/Pet.tsx

import React from "react";
import { PetName } from "~/components";

export type PetFieldProps = {
  text: string;
  icon: JSX.Element
};

export const PetField: React.FC<PetFieldProps> = ({
  text,
  icon
}) => {
  return (
    <>
      {icon}
      {text}
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: `Icon: JSX.Element`, can I set a `CatIcon` component as a element? If I use `<PetField Icon={<CatIcon />} text="Good Cat" />` to call this composed component, it got this error: `Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.`

Comment: Please check it again

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand it, but I'll make a try.

You can create an Icon component and pass through props the path or URL of the icon, that way you can create whatever icon you want.

```
# src/components/Icon/DogIcon/DogIcon.tsx

import React from "react";
...

export const DogIcon: React.FC<Size> = (props) => {
  return (
    <img src={props.path} />
  );
};
```

Something like that.